# Is the term Liouvillian number from algebra used uniformly in the literature?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

For the references, see below.

Is the term "Liouvillian number" from algebra used uniformly in the literature?

**Richardson writes:**
"The elementary numbers are the complex numbers which can be implicitly or explicitly defined by starting with the rationals and using addition, subtraction, multiplication and exponentiation.
...
The elementary numbers form an algebraically closed field, and are closed under application of the elementary functions.
...
A Liouvillian number is one obtained by a series of algebraic, exponential or logarithmic extensions of the rationals.
...
We have
... Liouvillian numbers ... $\subseteq$ Elementary numbers."

**But Chow writes:**
"The field $\mathbb{E}$ of EL numbers is the intersection of all subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ that are closed under $\exp$ and $\log$.
...
By analogy with elementary functions, Ritt thought of elementary numbers as the smallest
algebraically closed subfield $\mathbb{L}$ of $\mathbb{C}$ that is closed under exp and log. It so happens that terminology has evolved since Ritt, so that "elementary numbers" are now
numbers that can be specified implicitly as well as explicitly by exponential, logarithmic, and algebraic operations, and $\mathbb{L}$ is now sometimes called the field of Liouvillian numbers [16]."
$\ $

Until now, I couldn't find further texts with the term "Liouvillian number" with the meaning of one of the both articles.

I understand that as follows.

- Unlike Richardson, Chow says the Liouvillian numbers $\mathbb{L}$ are the elementary numbers.
- The Liouvillian numbers of Richardson are the EL numbers of Chow.

**Am I right? If not, where I'm wrong?**

I already know the above-mentioned terms from classical algebra.
$\ $

Richardson, D.: The Elementary Constant Problem. In Proc. Internat. Symp. on Symbolic and Algebraic Computation, Berkeley, July 27-29, 1992 (Ed.P. S. Wang). ACM Press, 1992.

[Chow, T.: What is a closed-form number. Am. Math. Monthly 106 (1999) (5) 440-448](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf)